# cnc-mon-0024 monitor service paging error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

While opening IBM Cognos Administration you can receive error "CNC-MON-0024 Monitor Service paging error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection."

The issue was resolved when the cognos connection was restarted.

I didn't understand why the error had occurred. Can someone please explain why this error had occurred.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many reason why it's happening: 
[Getting error CNC-MON-0024 Monitor Service paging error: No suitable driver](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21499572)
[CNC-MON-0024 Monitor Service paging error](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21449757)
[Launching the Cognos Administration Page displays an error](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21343394)
From my expirience, usually it's usually either incorect configuration or corrupted notification DB. 
In order to troubleshoot it, i suggest you split the content store db and the notification db as a first step:
[Change the Connection Properties for the Notification Database](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/c8bi/v8r4m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.inst_cr_winux.8.4.1.doc/inst_cr_winux_id17553configure_notification_db.html)